# Upload file with devesxpress

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress ASP components in my application.

On one page I have some controls with the following scenario: a user select document type from  dropdown list. After that he chooses file and uploads it to the server. The server parses the file applying the rules that rely on the user's document type choice. If the file is parsed successfully a label must be set with a success message. Otherwise it must be filled with an error message.

The DX ASPxUploadControl has an option called FileUploadMode that can be OnPageLoad or BeforePageLoad. This option defines the stage on which the file is uploaded.

So here is my problem.

If I set the option to "BeforePageLoad" then I can't get the selected value from the select box but I can set the text of the message label.

Otherwise, if the option is "OnPageLoad", I can get the selected value but it is too late to set the message text.

How can I get the selected value and set the message text at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you won't be able to achieve that without putting some Client Side (javascript) in your Html code.

Take [this example](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxFileManagerAndUploadDemos/UploadControl/CustomProgressPanel.aspx) to start over: note that some events are just handled in the Client Side, as I just pointed out.

Good Luck!